# ItemsControl - Bind Control's and Backing Collection's Sort Orders Together

Tags: wpf, data-binding, sorting, collections, itemscontrol

Is there a way to bind an `ItemsControl` (like `ListView` or `DataGrid`) to a sorted collection such that:

- whenever the collection is resorted via code, the `ItemsControl` automatically reflects the new sort order,
- AND whenever the `ItemsControl` is sorted, it re-sorts the collection?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()
```

method to get the default view of your ObservableCollection and apply the sort on that.

For example, below I'm sorting the ObservableCollection named 'authors' by BookTitle.

```
        ObservableCollection<Author> authors = new ObservableCollection<Author>();
        authors = PopulateCollection();

        // Sort by BookTitle
        System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView colView;
        colView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(authors);
        colView.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("BookTitle", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to define this two attributes on the bining:
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true
BindsDirectlyToSource=true

i did not tried this but it might work..

Answer (score 0):

Putting your items into an ObservableCollection and then binding to the ObservableCollection should do the trick.  Any sorting done on the ObservableCollection should "translate" to the UI layer.

Comment: Something like this is what I was hoping for but it didn't seem to work.